# When I save invalid data through a nested association, it shows up as valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm saving an invalid User record through an Account record during a registration wizard.  I have methods that let me conditionally skip validating certain User attributes.  When I check validity of the data through the association it shows as valid, when I check validity on it's own, it shows invalid.

ex:

```
$ account = Account.new
$ account.users.new(:email => nil)
$ account.save
=> true
$ account.users.last.valid?
=> true
$ User.last == account.users.last
=> true
$ User.last.valid?
=> false
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't do the same thing, since one is using memory and the other is using the database.

```
account.users.last.valid?
```

From the account object, take the users association (in memory), get the last element, check if valid.

```
User.last == account.users.last
```

Compare, primary key (:id field) of last user in database and last user in account.users association (in memory), and return true if the primary key is the same.

```
User.last.valid?
```

Check if the last user in the database is valid.

Try the following:

```
account.users(true).last.valid?
```

The true argument reloads the users association from the database.

Comment: Ah, that clears things up.  I've been scratching my head at my tests.. wondering what gives.  Thanks.